# Sheaves over a sheaf

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, stacks

Everything I write I mean in the in the sense of Lurie's [HTT](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/HTT.pdf).

Suppose that $ \mathcal{C}$ be a site and let $ F \in Fun( \mathcal{C}^{op} , \mathcal{S})$. Is it always/ever true that $ Sh(\mathcal{C})_{/F}$ is equivalent to $ Sh( \mathcal{C}_{/F}) \subseteq Fun(\mathcal{C}^{op}_{/F} , \mathcal{S})$? (The case I'm interested in is when $\mathcal{C}$ is $Aff$ or $derAff$) If this is discussed in HTT or elsewhere I'd be super happy with a reference. Thanks!

Comment: What is $\mathcal{S}$? (category of sets?)

Comment: @Qfwfq $\mathcal{S}$ is the category of spaces.

Comment: @Qfwfq it was my impression that when people refer to homotopy type theory they write HoTT

Comment: What is $\mathcal C / F$? Do you mean the overcategory of representables?

Comment: @AntonFetisov yes.

Comment: This is definitely true, but I might struggle to find a precise reference in Lurie. The way the proof usually goes is to first show that it holds for presheaves, then to define the Grothendieck topology on the category of elements such that the version for sheaves goes through. Somehow the main interesting part is showing this for presheaves.

Answer (score 5):

The version for presheaves is proven in

HTT, 5.1.6.12

To show that this equivalence carries over to sheaves, you need to think about how to pull the Grothendieck topology back to the category of elements.  I don't have a precise reference yet, but it should be somewhere around there. I'll take a look in the morning.

Somehow, Grothendieck topologies in Lurie's setup only rely on data in the homotopy category, so it shouldn't be surprising that this should now work by transfer of results from classical sheaf theory, but again, I have to find a precise reference for you.

Comment: I think you can use HTT.5.2.5.1 to get a formula for the induced adjunction between overcategories of presheaves and overcategories of sheaves, then pass through the equivalence for presheaves and read off what morphisms you invert.

Comment: @DylanWilson Yes, this was my thinking as well, but I'd like to finish this later with the rest of the info. =]

Comment: (I'm a little concerned though because it feels like we ought to require F to be a sheaf...)

Comment: Exactly my concern =].

Comment: Hey, thanks Harry and Dylan for the replies! I wrote that $F$ was a presheaf in my question because I thought it ought to hold in that generality but actually for the applications I had in mind $F$ will always be a sheaf. If it works when $F$ is a sheaf I'm satisfied.

Comment: The argument works over presheaves as over sheaves: Using the second assertion of HTT 5.2.5.1 we have an explicit description of the co-unit map of the sliced adjunction. If the left adjoint is left exact, this shows that this sliced co-unit is still an isomorphism, and thus that the sliced adjunction is indeed a localization. This also shows that slicing over a presheaf or over its sheafification give equivalent localizations, so that it is sufficient to consider the case of sheaves.